# How to show hidden content after few minutes of display in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The application I'm developing is a game.What I want to do is i want the below layout to react such that once the circle is clicked the hidden content gets displayed. I would humbly appreciated just a small demo using one button just to display the hidden content from the circle. Thanks in advance.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back1"
    tools:context=".MainScreen">



    <View
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use an imagebutton and in onclick listener of the button add `your_hidden_item.setVisibility(View.Visible);`

Comment: Waoh :) thank you soo much. This was bothering me. Thanks.

Comment: Great..:) Could you please mark the answer as accepted if that really helped you..

Comment: definitely that was nice. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you yo use an `ImageButton` and in the onClickListener make the item visible as below

```
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.your_button);
    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            your_hidden_item.setVisibility(View.Visible);
        }
    });
```